# Modify SystemVerilog module parameter value in Verilator simulation (C++)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verilator

Is it possible to modify the parameters for a verilated SystemVerilog from a testbench written in C++. For example, consider the module below.

```
module my_module #(
    parameter WIDTH = 16
)
(
    input logic i_clk, // input clock
    input logic i_rst, // input reset
    output logic [7:0] o_out // output
);
```

Say I verilate this module, I am able to do the following in C++ after instancing the verilated module:

```
// Something to the effect of...
VerilatedContext* contextp = new VerilatedContext;
Vmy_module* top = new Vmy_module{contextp};
//...
top->i_rst = 1;
```

If I wanted to modify the default value for the *WIDTH* parameter (from within the C++ code), how would I go about doing that?

I've tried marking it public (via `/*verilator public*/`) to no avail. I have also used the DPI interface to read other internal module signals, however, I'm not sure if they can be applied to write/modify parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot override the value of a parameter at runtime in Verilator. The `/*verilator public*/` pragma is for access to a signal from your C++ testbench.

You can override a parameter before your SystemVerilog code has been translated to C++ using the `-G` options.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I had seen the -G option in amongst the verilator documentation, but it would make the workflow a bit cumbersome if I wanted to test a variety of parameters. Do you know if there are plans to add the capability of modifying the parameters, programmatically, at some point? Without understanding some of the internals of verilator, it seems having the ability to specify them as part of the constructor for the verilated module would be a nice addition

Comment: Suggest you ask that question [here](https://github.com/verilator/verilator/issues)